# Box Not Floating

Tags: css, css-float

Have looked, but did not find a suitable answer.

My question is simple: Trying to float, without success.

Here's the page: http://www.linguashop.com/course/classic.php

The red box on the left should float left, with the greybox and menu coming up on the right.

[image]

The CSS I am using is below:

```css
.logo2013,      
.logo2013 a     {margin:0;width:220px;height:120px;}

.logo2013   {float:left;}

.logo2013   {border:1px solid #f00; border-top-left-radius: 10px; }

.logo2013 a     {display:block;text-indent:-9999px;}

.greybanner2013 {height:91px; line-height:1; background:#f7f6f2 left top;}  
.greybanner2013 {border:1px solid #ddd; border-top-right-radius: 10px;}

.greybanner2013 .fontsize32 h2 {padding-top:5px; font-size:32px;color:#777;font-weight:bold; margin:0; margin-left: 20px; }

.greybanner2013 .foreign {font-size:32px;color:#FF9300;font-weight:bold; display:inline; margin:0; margin-left: 20px; padding:0; }

.greybanner2013 .translation {font-size:28px;color:#AAA;font-weight:normal; display:inline; margin-left:  10px; }

/*menu*/

.nav2013 {height:28px; background-color:#787065; border:1px solid #ccc; }

.nav2013 ul {/*float:right;*/ list-style:none;margin:4px 0;padding:0}

.nav2013 li {float:left;padding:0 24px 0 22px;margin:0; right top no-repeat*/}

.nav2013 li a {font-family:Verdana,Arial,SunSans-Regular,Sans-Serif; display:block;color:#ebeae8;text-decoration:none;font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; }

.nav2013 li:last-child {padding-right:15px;background:none}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

David

Comment: looks good to me in firefox. http://i.imgur.com/dfMjAl3.png

Comment: is it supposed to float left all the way?

Comment: Hi David. I had originally included an image showing  how it should be but did not have enough  reputation to include in image. (One needs a reputation of 10).  Please have a look at the 'should be' image  here: http://www.linguashop.com/banner.jpg

Comment: Oops... Thanksfor the responses. The grey and dark grey should be  to the  right of the red box.  Should I perhaps  "float right" on these.  Have a look closely at the top left hand corner.  The  red is rounded but the grey box is also there un-rounded.  Please see www.linguashop.com/corner.bmp   That's proof that the grey box is right at the left margin.

Comment: @DavidStephens i think i got what you want. see the update in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what i am seeing
[image]

if you want to float the red box to the left all the way;

then add `logo2013` directly under `banner2013`

it will create this

[image]

**UPDATE**

i think your problem is the border radius on the upper left corner. this should fix it.

add this to `.greybanner2013`

`border-top-left-radius:10px;`

the logo you put there that has a border radius like that can cover the grey area behind there. 
to actually float the red box left and rest right while keeping them in the middle of the screen requires a little more work and perhaps change of html and css quite a bit.

you can set the background color of `logo2013` class to `white` and that will give the similar effect as well.